# Is there any way to enhance syntax highlighting in RAD Studio code editor?

Tags: delphi, pascal, rad-studio

Even if I think the title asks the question by itself, I'd like to show an example of what I'm talking about. When working with other languages, I see this:

Python in VSCode:
[image]

And working with Delphi's code editor (or in VSCode with DelphiLSP), I have this:

Delphi in VSCode:
[image]

Delphi's Code Editor:
[image]

Delphi's Extended Example:
[image]

Isn't there an external/third-party plugin to improve the Syntax Highlighting within the code editor?

I've googled a lot and didn't find anything (but maybe I'm doing it wrong, as most of the results talk about Components with Syntax Highlighting).

I know it's a silly necessity, but maybe it's time to catch up with other languages in terms of Syntax Highlighting.

Edit: Added a bigger example in Delphi Editor to get closer to the content of the example in Python.

About DITE (Delphi IDE Theme Editor): I've been using it to clone what is possible from GruvBox but my current problem lies on **what can actually get different colors**

For example this comparison:

Pascal Colouring:
[image]

Python Colouring:
[image]

C++ Colouring (With Better C++ and Popping and Locking Theme):
[image]

I'm pointing there is not (and it seems one is not able to do it if wants so) a way to get different colors on variable names vs. function names, or function names vs. parameters, or class names vs class methods I believe it's possible on VSCode (cus this distinguishing seems not to exist for C++ or JS in some themes), but not so sure about the Delphi/RAD Studio Code Editor.

Comment: What does the "Delphi On Code Editor" look like on VS Code? You're comparing two different sets of code, with the latter having virtually nothing to highlight

Comment: [Easily Customize The Syntax Editor Coloring In Delphi With The Third Party Delphi IDE Theme Editor](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/easily-customize-the-syntax-editor-coloring-in-delphi-with-the-third-party-delphi-ide-theme-editor/)

Comment: GN! Addressed both comments in the latest edit.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using Cnpack or GExpert.
Both are popular third-party IDE plugins for RAD Studio, and they provide various enhancements to the RAD Studio IDE, including features related to syntax highlighting.

Comment: Cool! Checked both options, it seems GExpert isnt't being updated anymore, is it working in D12?

Comment: GExperts is still being updated, but not at the original site.  See https://blog.dummzeuch.de/experimental-gexperts-version/